# Does number fall in interval in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Is there a better way than the following:

```
(defn in-interval?
  "Returns a predicate that tests if its argument falls in
  the inclusive interval [a, b]."
  [a b]
  (fn [x] (and (>= x a) (<= x b))))
```

In use:

```
((in-interval? 5 8) 5.5) ; true
((in-interval? 5 8) 9)   ; false
```

I don't want to use `range`, for example, because that constructs a lazy sequence.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Is there a better way than the following:

[Yes](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/%3C=).

```
(<= 5 8 8.5)
```

It works with any number of arguments and check if they are ordered. With 3 arguments, it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Also worth noting, you can read the variadic versions of the comparison operators as "ascending", "descending", "strictly ascending", and "strictly descending".

Comment: Thanks! This is nice way of demonstrating Blacksad's answer: `(map #(<= 2 % 4) [1 2 3 4 5])`

Comment: And Clojure continues to surprise me with all of the way things just work in ways which make sense.

Comment: @deterb That was my exact thought when I discovered `clojure.core/<` and so many great things in Clojure

Comment: This works not because there's a literal check whether a number is in a range; it works because `<=` checks whether the numbers are monotonically decreasing. This has the same effect of checking whether a number lies in the range.