# Shorthand Evaluation of Num >= Low Num and < High Num Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Came across this post about shorthand evaluation of statements with comparator operations in Clojure.

[Does number fall in interval in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393451/does-number-fall-in-interval-in-clojure)

So, this makes sense to me:

```
(<= 4 7 7)
=>true
```

And this makes sense:

```
(< 4 7 7)
    =>false
```

But what about if I needed the statement to evaluate to true if the middle number is **greater than or equal** to 4, and **less than** 7? Is there a shorthand way to do this and avoid doing something like:

```
(and (< 7 7) (>= 7 4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in shorthand for this, but...

> greater than or equal to 4, and less than 7

can also be written as `(<= 4 x 6)` or `(< 3 x 7)`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will just use what I had before. Would've used the examples you mentioned but in the scenario I envisioned, floats like 3.5 should make the statement false, and 6.5 true.

Answer (score 1):

Half-open intervals are quite common. If you need to use them often, you may want to write a function:

```
(defn <=< [a b c]
  (and (<= a b) (< b c)))
```

or maybe a macro:

```
(defmacro <=< [a b c]
  `(let [b# ~b] (and (<= ~a b#) (< b# ~c))))
```

Comment: your naming is strange: how do  you differentiate between `a<=b & b<c` and `a<b & b<=c`?

Comment: I would name it  `<<=`, but I agree more thoughts should be put on those names in an actual library.

Comment: @erdos: I believe that <=/< is much more common than </<=, because it is the default way to give non-overlapping intervals.

Comment: @coredump: I would make this a function, not a macro.

Comment: @Svante You are right, I saw "and" and wanted to keep the "shortcut" evaluation, but that's not how other relational operators work.